# pass parameter to IServiceLocator

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, service-locator

I have a ViewModel class which I want to resolve via the unity ServiceLocator, but my viewModel requires a parameter to the constructor. The parameter's type is one of the entities in my application (a Customer object) rather than some service implementation. I know that coding against the Unitycontainer itself I can pass a paramater like this:

```
 _container.Resolve<CustomerDetailViewModel>(new ParameterOverrides {{"customer", customer}});
```

but if I dont have direct access to the container I need to go via the ServiceLocator like this:

```
(CustomerDetailViewModel)ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<CustomerDetailViewModel>();
```

However using the second approach I have no way to pass in any parameters to the ServiceLocator. Is there any way this can be done? Is it "wrong" to get an instance of the Container from the ServiceLocator and then use that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to inject an entity (`Customer` in this case) into a class. Entities are short lived objects and they don't tend to be good candidates for being injected.

Instead of injecting a `Customer`, inject a `ICustomerRepository` service. You can register an `ICustomerRepository` implementation in the startup path of the application and this way you won't have to call the container directly, which makes the application design cleaner and the unit tests easier.

Comment: I hear what you are saying Steven, but in my instance the Customer entity comes as the selected item of an itemsControl (the master) and I want to pass it through to me detail viewModel. Somewhere along the line I need to provide the entity to the details viewModel - perhaps just using a Customer property on the details viewModel is the way to go, but it would be nice to have it go into the constructor....

Comment: When you use dependency injection all the way, there is simply no way to get the Customer object in through the constructor, simply because the detail viewModel will be injected in the constructor of the master. At the time your code runs, the detail viewModel is already created. Doing it that way will ensure best testability. In the constructor you only want to inject dependencies. In this case your customer is not a dependency, but just state information. You should set it as property or supply it as method argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you write a wrapper for the ServiceLocator you can hold the unity container within the wrapper and the expose an additional resolve method overload that takes the ParameterOverrides property.  Then the method could use the unity container to do the resolution as per your first code snippet rather than the ServiceLocator code snippet.